# javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Login failed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to run a hadoop job (version 18.3) on my windows machine but I get the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Login failed: CreateProcess: bash -c groups error=2
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UnixUserGroupInformation.login(UnixUserGroupInformation.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UnixUserGroupInformation.login(UnixUserGroupInformation.java:275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.configureCommandLineOptions(JobClient.java:557)
        ... 3 more
```

The same job works fine in an another windows machine. Do I have may be something wrong in the settings variabls? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe bash is not available on your PATH?

Do you have Cygwin installed correctly?

I really like [this tutorial by Vlad Korolev](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html) to set up Hadoop on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, installing cygwin helps.